# python: extract variables values from `json` and use in `jupyter` notebook for a function throwing an error

Tags: python, json, function, jupyter-notebook

I have a `par.json` file were i stored the variable values. And fetched the values in `.py` file successfully. I'm trying to run all function of `.py` file in jupyter notebook (all is in same location) where `.py` file already getting values from `json` file but while running in `jupyter notebook` it is throwing an error called as `'b_threshold' is not defined`
json file I have

```
{
    "mul": 200,
    "b_threshold": 2,
    "a_threshold": 5,

}
```

the multi.py file snippet is below

```
def h_b_acc(data, har={}): 
    trr = data.tt.unique() 
    # global b_threshold, a_threshold, mul
    for tr in trr:
        temp_dict = {}
        
        temp_df = data.loc[data['tt']==tr].copy()
        temp_df['b_event'] = temp_df['aci'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < b_threshold else 0)
        temp_df['a_event'] = temp_df['aci'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > a_threshold else 0)
  

    
        total_d_dis = temp_df['dd'].max() - temp_df['dd'].min()

        temp_dict['b_s'] = (2015* mul)/ total_d_dis 
   


        temp_dict['a_s']= (2016 * mul)/ total_d_dis 

        har['tr_' + str(tr)] =   temp_dict  
#         print(temp_dict)
    return har

if __name__ =='__main__':
    try:
        with open(r'path\par.json', "r") as prm_mp:
            pp = json.load(prm_mp)
            
            
        b_threshold = pp.get('b_threshold', 2)
        a_threshold = pp.get('a_threshold', 5) 
        mul = pp.get(['mul'],200)

   except:
        print("Parameter mapping file not parsed")
```

loaded json file in following way in jupyter notebook

```
with open(r'path\par.json', "r") as prm_mp:
            pp = json.load(prm_mp)
            
            
        b_threshold = pp.get('b_threshold', 2)
        a_threshold = pp.get('a_threshold', 5) 
        mul = pp.get(['mul'],200)


har_1 = multi.h_b_acc(tm)
har_1
```

showing following error .. how can I import it ? or may I wrong in writing function.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imported module `multi` and its function `h_b_acc()` do not have access to your  variables `a_threshold` and `b_threshold`. I recommend that you modify `multi.h_b_acc()` to pass them as optional arguments, so you can use the function in the Jupyer Notebook, as well as use your global variables in `multi.py` when needed. (It's also probably a good idea to ALL-CAPS your global variables)

```
def h_b_acc(data, a_threshold=A_THRESHOLD, b_threshold=B_THRESHOLD, mul=MUL, har={}): 
    trr = data.tt.unique() 
    for tr in trr:
        temp_dict = {}
        
        temp_df = data.loc[data['tt']==tr].copy()
        temp_df['b_event'] = temp_df['aci'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < b_threshold else 0)
        temp_df['a_event'] = temp_df['aci'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > a_threshold else 0)
  

    
        total_d_dis = temp_df['dd'].max() - temp_df['dd'].min()

        temp_dict['b_s'] = (2015* mul)/ total_d_dis 
   


        temp_dict['a_s']= (2016 * mul)/ total_d_dis 

        har['tr_' + str(tr)] =   temp_dict  
#         print(temp_dict)
    return har
```

This, way, in your Jupyter Notebook, you can do the following:

```
with open(r'path\par.json', "r") as prm_mp:
            pp = json.load(prm_mp)
            
            
        b_threshold = pp.get('b_threshold', 2)
        a_threshold = pp.get('a_threshold', 5) 
        mul = pp.get(['mul'],200)


har_1 = multi.h_b_acc(tm, a_threshold, b_threshold, mul)
har_1
```

Comment: where you defined the `A_THRESHOLD` and `B_THRESHOLD` ? did you just added for the completion of the function?

Comment: It's good practice that you all-caps your global variables. So wherever you define your global variables right now would be where you define `A_THRESHOLD` and `B_THRESHOLD`.